# Hashed passwords not matching

Tags: php

I created a registration and a login script which hash the password with salt exactly the same way, however when the user attempts to login using their password, the hashed login password and the one stored in the database differ, it was working a couple of days ago and I haven't changed anything in the login and registration scripts.

Here is what the stored credentials are

DBEMAIL: `jd@gmail.com`

DBPASSWORD: 
`addb18f27b6970082727069aa5853116223c5ab46f46a7b07340757804670aef61311ff0254ec45ea78d9ea6d8afb2cefdf3afd6bd4947f6fc558f46703fac1c`

Here is what the User inserted credentials are:

UEMAIL: `jd@gmail.com`

UPASSWORD: `4123363f30664825356a238fe7a568910315e6f6aa8a57d0264844c641e856ab207200f4c75a532b2ebecdbd062bff31da101d973ab0f83eaefd2323a39a4a88`

They are hashed using:

```
$salt   = "salinger";
$hashed = hash_hmac("sha512", $password, $salt);
```

The full registration function (it's messy I know but it works (until now):

```
function registerUser($firstname, $surname, $email, $password, $secretQ, $secretA,    $address, $city, $postcode) {
    $flag = array();
    $validEmail = validateEmail($email);
    if (($validEmail) == true) {
         //Do not flag
    } else {
        array_push($flag, 1);
    }
    if ((textOnly("First name", $firstname) == true) || ((textOnly("Surname", $surname)) == true) || ((textOnly("City", $city)) == true)) {
        array_push($flag, 1);
    }
    if ((emptyField($firstname)) || (emptyField($surname)) || (emptyField($email)) || (emptyField($password)) || (emptyField($secretA)) || (emptyField($address)) || (emptyField($city)) || (emptyField($postcode))) {
        array_push($flag, 1);
    }
    if (validPostcode($postcode) == false) {
        array_push($flag, 1);
    }
    if (duplicateEmail($email) == true) {
        array_push($flag, 1);
    }
    if (validatePassword($password) == false) {
        array_push($flag, 1);
    } else {
        $password = validatePassword($password);
    }
    switch ($secretQ) {
        case 1:
            $secretQ = "Your mothers maiden name?";
            break;
        case 2:
            $secretQ = "Name of your first pet?";
            break;
        case 3:
            $secretQ = "The name of your high school?";
            break;
        case 4:
            $secretQ = "Your favourite instrument?";
            break;
    }

    $salt   = "salinger";
    $hashed = hash_hmac("sha512", $password, $salt);

    if (!empty($flag)) {
        echo "There are errors with your registration, go back and ammend it. <br /> <a href=\"register.php\">&lt;&lt; Back</a>";
    } else {
        if ((isset($firstname)) && (isset($surname)) && (isset($email)) && (isset($password)) && (isset($secretQ)) && (isset($secretA)) && (isset($address)) && (isset($city)) && (isset($postcode))) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (forename, surname, email, password, secretQ, secretA, address_street, address_city, address_postcode, member_type) VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$email', '$hashed', '$secretQ', '$secretA', '$address', '$city', '$postcode', 'User');";
            header("Location: index.php");
        } else {
            array_push($flag, 1);
        }
    }
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

The login function:

```
function loginUser($email, $password) {
    if (validateEmail($email) == true) {
        $sql    = "SELECT customerid, forename, email, password, secretA, member_type FROM customer WHERE email = '$email'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $DBid       = $record['customerid'];
            $DBemail    = $record['email'];
            $DBpassword = $record['password'];
            $DBforename = $record['forename'];
            $DBsecretA  = $record['secretA'];
            $DBmember   = $record['member_type'];
        }

        if (!$result) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }

        $salt   = "salinger";
        $hashed = hash_hmac("sha512", $password, $salt);

        echo "DBEMAIL: $DBemail   DBPASSWORD: $DBpassword <br/>";
        echo "UEMAIL: $email  UPASSWORD: $hashed <br/>";

        if (($email == $DBemail) && ($hashed == $DBpassword)) {
            $match = true;
        } else {
            $match = false;
        }

        if ($match == true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['userid']   = $DBid;
            $_SESSION['Active']   = true;
            $_SESSION['forename'] = $DBforename;
            $_SESSION['type']     = $DBmember;
            header("Location: member.php");
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect credentials.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid email address!";
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: If the call to `hash_hmac()` no longer produces the same output, I don't think the rest of the code is relevant. Has your host recently upgraded to a newer PHP version, such as 5.4?

Comment: show us code from where you called `registerUser` ?

Comment: how many characters do you have allotted for the password field in MySQL? You are probably storing a truncated hash.

Comment: Btw, the salt's main purpose is to increase the entropy of the hashed string, so you shouldn't be using a plain string but a selection of more exotic symbols.

Comment: The password field in the database is 350 characters, I over compensated so this is definitely not the case. 

The register user function being called the variables are the POST values:

`registerUser($firstname, $surname, $email, $password, $secretQ, $secretA, $address, $city, $postcode);`

I'll look into the hosts update. 

Also I understand that the salt should be more complicated, however this was just for testing, if I publish the website I'll change the salt to a more complex selection.

The PHP version of the host hasn't changed it is still 5.3.14

Comment: Building on what @moonwave99 said, your salt should also be unique per-user. Using the same salt for everyone makes it easy to bruteforce everyone's password at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In registerUser, I'd take a closer look at this:

```
...
if (validatePassword($password) == false) {
    array_push($flag, 1);
} else {
    $password = validatePassword($password);
}
...
```

`$password` will be overwritten, it appears, if it is a valid password. If all the passwords are the same in the database, then it's likely that $password is being set to `true`, and that's the value that's salted. Depending on how you use validatePassword, you may be able to remove the else-clause, leaving this:

```
...
if (validatePassword($password) == false) {
    array_push($flag, 1);
}
...
```

Comment: I have actually just facepalmed, I can't believe I missed this. Thank you very much, works perfectly.